# Converting HTML webpage to React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My question is about the standards of React and JSX. I am unsure how to formulate a page using React. Do I break down my page into components and render everything through JSX? Or is it a combination of HTML with rendered components strewn throughout?

I have been unable to find any succinct response to this question, but from what I have gathered, is that I break the webpage into only components.

Comment: usually React will render your entire website/app so you'll have a [single page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a combination of HTML with rendered components strewn throughout. You can however also have only one master "component" to render the entire app and it's "sub" components rendered within.

I don't think the term component is the best one here but I get what you mean rather I think you mean React Element.

Generally it is preferred and easier to just use React Elements where you need React eg for a search bar and have everything else in HTML.